# Warning: The identity of this website has not been verified

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I have just launched my website based on WordPress. However, when I use my cellphone to visit my website. It gives me a exclamation mark in the web address with `Warning: The identity of this website has not been verified`.

I have verified the `HTML Tag` with `Google Search Console`. I am not sure if there are any steps I need to verify so that the website is not throw warnings.

Every comment and recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: have you installed SSL?

Comment: install one and that should fix it, you can use lets encrypt and if don't wants to mange certificate yourself, use cloudflare's DNS free services, which provides a free SSL.

Comment: @user969068 much appreciated. At least I have a clue to solve my problem.

Comment: @ThoVu It's not really just a clue, it's the whole problem. The SSL certificate is verification that the website is in fact the website it says it is.

Comment: Thanks @GrumpyCrouton and user969068 so much for your help. It is truly a whole problem for me to wok on.

Answer (score 0):

Install Really Simple SSL from WordPress repository via:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

That will sure solve your problem